# get value from array inside object react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have object and inside him group arrays i try get some value from elements of array and always get errors. When I use console.log(country.geoPosition) I can see data but can't access why??? I create Object from fetch data

```
const [country, setCountry] = useState([{
    item01:[],
    cityName:[],
    stateName:[],
    timeZone:[{
      Code: "", 
      GmtOffset : ""
    }],
    geoPosition: [{
      latitude: "",
      longitude: ""
    }]
  }]);

setCountry(
      {
        item01:[data[0]], 
        cityName:[data[0].EnglishName],
        stateName:[data[0].Country.EnglishName],
        timeZone:[{
          Code: data[0].TimeZone.Code,
          GmtOffset : data[0].TimeZone.GmtOffset
        }],
        geoPosition:[{
          latitude : data[0].GeoPosition.Latitude,
          longitude : data[0].GeoPosition.Longitude
        }]

      });
  }
```

i try console.log(country.geoPosition.latitude) and get error but if i try console.log(country.geoPosition) code works and i see values

Comment: When you initially set your country state it's an object within an array: `useState([{` But from your description I think you want `useState({`.

Comment: You are switching from array to obejct ([] in useState, {} in setCountry). You hsould also not copy the props into your state on every render. If you do that, you can skip the state altogether an just use the props. Also geoPosition is an array so to access it type: country.geoPosition[0].latitude or remove the [] brackets around geoPostion.

Comment: i must use props in state because after type and hit button props must be update...i remove bracket from useState and now works that was problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You have created geoPosition as an array.

```
geoPosition: [{
  latitude: "",
  longitude: ""
}]
```

In order to access the latitude you will have to use `country.geoPosition[0].latitude`.

If your geoPosition only has a single latitude and longtitude change the geoPosition in your state as follows.

```
geoPosition: {
  latitude: "",
  longitude: ""
}
```

The square brackets are removed in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the index, try

```
country.geoPosition[0].latitude
```

Or change the structure of your code so that `geoPosition` is an object not an array

```
geoPosition: {
  latitude: "",
  longitude: ""
}
```

hope this helps